# External URL handling in QWC2

Tags: qgis-server, url, qwc2

I have currently set up a working QWC2 environment using Apache. Now, my QWC2 is accessible through qgis.#####.com:8088. One of the layers contains a column with a url (e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)). When accessing this url from the feature info window in QWC2, the url is automatically redirected to qgis.#####.com:8088/www.google.com. I.e., the absolute url defined in the attribute table is appended after the server name.

In the attribute table, the URL is defined as follows:
href="google.com" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank"

I'm wondering if there is some setting regarding external URL handling (config.json?).

How does QWC2 handle URLs to external websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not an absolute URL to an external website but a relative one. Try to use a full, absolute URL like `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: That did the trick... sometimes solutions come as easy as this. Thank you!